# Converting a Tableau report with different measures for each row to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

I'm working on a project where we are converting a client from Tableau to PBI. One of the Tableau reports I'm converting looks like this:

[image]

Each row is a different calculation (measure). I can achieve a similar look, with regards to the column headers, in PBI by using a matrix. However, there isn't a way, that I know of, to apply a different measure for each row. The only way I can think of to do this is to create three matrix tables and stack them on top of each other. It won't look nearly as good but I can generate the same results. Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Measure Names pill on Rows, Measure Values on Text and your date fields on Columns. That should give you when you want.